# One cell table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to accomplish a one cell table view, like this image

[image: this]

I want to accomplish basically that.

Comment: Can you provide us your source code?

Comment: It isn't mine - it's an example from apple

Comment: What problem are you having? What error occurs? So far you have not asked a question.

Comment: If you only need one cell, why do you need a table view at all? Table views provide scrollable content in cells like a single column spreadsheet. Instead of a single-cell spreadsheet, why not just create a view controller with an image view, 2 labels or text fields, and a button? It would give the same appearance much more simply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a `UITableView` with one cell just set it on `numberOfRowsInSection` like that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 1
}
```